# ClassNotFoundException: xsbt/WeakLog scala intellij

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble Running a scala code on Intellij with windows 7.

I have installed Intellij with scala 2.12 now I am creating a simple mvn application with hello world example as below:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println ("hello")
  }
}
```

While running the same on intellij I am getting the error as below: Would be good if someone can help me for same.

```
Error:scalac: Error: xsbt/WeakLog
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xsbt/WeakLog
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.newCompiler(CompilerInterface.scala:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbt.WeakLog
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
```

Below is the pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
     <artifactId>elastic4s-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>elastic4s-tcp_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sksamuel.elastic4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>elastic4s-http_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: @λAllquantorλ : I have edited the post to include pom.